# SELECT based on foreign key, to change reference

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables: `Equipment`, and `Equipment_Type`:

```
+-------------------------------+
| EqId [PK] | ETId [FK] | EqNum |
+-------------------------------+
| 1         | 1         | ABC   |
| 2         | 1         | DEF   |
| 3         | 3         | GHI   |

+-------------------------------+
| ETId [PK] | Code | Discipline |
+-------------------------------+
| 1         | MOT  | ELEC       |
| 2         | MOT  | MECH       |
| 3         | SW   | ELEC       |
```

So from this example, we can see that both of our equipment are electrical motors.

However, due to a misunderstanding in the initial population, all of the equipment types were identified a `ELEC` disciplines. Since then, the `MECH` equipment has been identified, and I have to find all of the equipment that has been duplicated in the `Equipment_Type` table, and change them to reference the `MECH` equipment types instead.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM Equipment EQ 
INNER JOIN Equipment_Type ET on ET.ETId = EQ.ETId
WHERE ET.Discipline = 'MECH';
```

Which (obviously) returns no results - as with all the other `JOIN` queries.

What I want to achieve is a search that will select *only* the Equipment that has an `ELEC` Equipment Type that is *also* a `MECH` equipment type. I realise this requires a nested query, but I'm not sure where to place it.

So the search should return:

```
+---------------------------+
| EqNum | ETId | Discipline |
+---------------------------+
| DEF   | 1    | ELEC       |
```

Because that entry needs to be changed to the `MECH` discipline (i.e. ETId = 2 instead of 1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method that aggregates the types to get the codes that have both disciplines:

```
select e.*
from equipment e join
     equipment_type et
     on e.etid = et.etid join
     (select et.code
      from equipment_type et
      group by et.code
      having sum(discipline = 'MECH') > 0 and sum(discipline = 'ELEC') > 0
     ) ett
     on ett.code = et.code;
```

Another method would use two joins:

```
select e.*
from equipment e join
     equipment_type ete
     on e.etid = ete.etid and ete.discipline = 'ELEC' join
     equipement_type etm
     on ete.code = etm.code and etm.discipline = 'MECH';
```

This version might be faster with the right indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
select eq_id, eq_name,et_id,description from
(select eq_id,eq_name from equipment) as a

left join

(select et_id,description from equipment_type) as b
on a.eq_id = b.et_id where description = 'ELEC';
```

IF YOU WANT TO INCLUDE 'MECH';

```
select eq_id, eq_name,et_id,description from
(select eq_id,eq_name from equipment) as a

left join

(select et_id,description from equipment_type) as b
on a.eq_id = b.et_id where description = 'ELEC' or description = 'MECH';
```

CHANGE 'ELEC' TO 'MECH':

```
select eq_id, eq_name,et_id,

case when description = 'ELEC' then 'MECH' else description end  as description,

'MECH' as MECH_FIELD from
(select eq_id,eq_name from equipment) as a

left join

(select et_id,description from equipment_type) as b
on a.eq_id = b.et_id where description = 'ELEC' or description = 'MECH';
```